# Is it possible to reference a byte?

Tags: kotlin

In C, it is possible to create an array and have a pointer pointing to a specific byte of that array, like this:

```
    char array[] = "This is not a question.";
    char *ptr = strchr(array, ' '); // points to the first space
```

This is extremely useful both for performance and reduce memory usage when parsing, sometimes I create data structures that just points to different bytes of the same buffer. I wonder if it is convenient and possible to do the same in Kotlin.

Comment: Java/Kotlin usually use indexes for such purposes

Comment: There is no direct memory arithmetics in languages like Java/Kotlin

Comment: That means I have to create new objects to store the chunk of data I desire?

Comment: @stare it depends on what you want to do. Should ask about specific problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent in Java and Kotlin is simply to store an index into the array (or String).

Remember that the JVM has very powerful dynamic compilation and optimisation, so while in C that would be less efficient, on the JVM it generally won't be.  (The difference generally wouldn't be significant in most applications, anyway.)

Also note that Kotlin uses Unicode, so a character is not the same as a byte.  A `Character` is an unsigned two-byte number.  (Characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane are stored as a surrogate pair.)

So the equivalent would be:

```
val string = "This is not a question."
val i = string.indexOf(' ') // = 4, index of the first space
```

or

```
val array = byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val i2 = array.indexOf(3) // = 2, index of the first occurrence of 3
```